# How to call parametric constructor appropriately in Julia?

Tags: julia

I wanted to call the constructor of composite type `WeightedPool1D` but I tried both `WeightedPool1D(mask)` and `WeightedPool1D{Float64}(mask)` but it did not work.

Thanks!

Julia version: 1.6.1

My code:

```
# creating composite type
struct WeightedPool1D{T}
    n::Int
    c::Int
    mask::Matrix{Bool}
    weight::Matrix{T}
    function WeightedPool1D(mask::Matrix{Bool}) where T
        c, n = size(mask)
        weight = randn(T, c, n) / n
        new{T}(n, c, mask, weight)
    end
end

# create argument
mask = zeros(Bool, 3, 3)
```

Calling `w = WeightedPool1D(mask)` gives the error

```
julia> w = WeightedPool1D(mask)
ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined
```

Calling `w = WeightedPool1D{Float64}(mask)` gives the error

```
julia> w = WeightedPool1D{Float64}(mask)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching WeightedPool1D{Float64}(::Matrix{Bool})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is the inner constructor. There is nothing (from the input to the constructor) that defines what `T` should be.

If you want a default value of `T`, say `Float64`, you can define the following inner constructors

```
struct WeightedPool1D{T}
    n::Int
    c::Int
    mask::Matrix{Bool}
    weight::Matrix{T}

    # General constructor for any T, call as WeightedPool1D{Float64}(...)
    function WeightedPool1D{T}(mask::Matrix{Bool}) where T
        c, n = size(mask)
        weight = randn(T, c, n) / n
        new{T}(n, c, mask, weight)
    end
   
    # Construtors that defines a default T, call as WeightedPool1D(...)
    function WeightedPool1D(mask::Matrix{Bool})
        return WeightedPool1D{Float64}(mask) # Calls the other constructor, now with T = Int
    end
end
```

Example calls:

```
mask = zeros(Bool, 3, 3)

WeightedPool1D(mask)
WeightedPool1D{Float32}(mask)
```